# averaging the temperature

Tags: python

I was having trouble with my program since it doesn't list the years and temperature. Also how can I print a message saying that the temperature increased from the year before?

Here is my code:

```
years = int(input('How many years do you want to calculate the temperature outside?'))
first = int(input('What year would you want to start calculating?'))
month = 12
for year in range(1, years, + 1):
    for months in range(1, 13):
     get = float(input('What is the average temperature for month {} '.format(months)))
     if get < -100 or get > 200:
      print('Repeat a valid number.')
     get += get + months
     get = get / 12
print('Years\tTemperature')
print('-------------------')
print(years, '\t', format(get, '.2f'), sep ='')
```

Comment: I think that you are trying to ask for two things: 1- How to list the years, 2- How to say that the temperature listed in the previous year. However you don't make that clear in your question.

Answer (score 0):

It would be relatively easy to do if you first stored all the user input in a list and then processed and print the results that afterwards.

When doing that, you can skip checking the previous year's average by initially giving it an intial value of `None` and then checking for that when calculating determining if there was an increase.

Here's what I mean:

```
years = int(input('How many years do you want to calculate the temperature outside? '))
first = int(input('What year would you want to start calculating? '))
data = []

for year in range(first, first+years):
    print('\nEnter temperatures for year', year)
    month_temps = []
    for month in range(1, 13):
        prompt = "What's the average temperature for month {}? ".format(month)
        # Loop until user enters a valid monthly temperature.
        while True:
            try:
                avg_temp = float(input(prompt))
            except ValueError:
                print("Sorry, didn't understand that, try again.")
                continue
            if -100 <= avg_temp <= 200:  # Valid number?
                break
            else:
                print("Sorry, but that's not valid, try again.")
                continue
        month_temps.append(avg_temp)

    # Compute the year's average temperature from the monthly ones.
    avg_temp = sum(month_temps) / len(month_temps)
    data.append((year, avg_temp))

print()
fmt_spec = '{:<4} {:>22} {:>16}'
print(fmt_spec.format('Year', 'Temperature', 'Increase'))
prev_temp = None
for year, avg_temp in data:
    difference = (avg_temp - prev_temp) if prev_temp is not None else 0
    print(fmt_spec.format(year, avg_temp, 'Yes' if difference > 0 else ''))
    prev_temp = avg_temp
```